# What's CHANGE_BEGIN/END in this repository?

Tags: git

To clearly demarcate the changes made in a git branch, it seems nvidia have used some NVCHANGE_BEGIN/END tags [in a branch of UE4](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/compare/release...NvPhysX:VXGI-4.10) (that most of you won't have access to) like so (in the source code):

```
// NVCHANGE_BEGIN: Add VXGI
// some code here
// NVCHANGE_END: Add VXGI
```

and similar entries in the .git file:

```
# NVCHANGE_BEGIN: Add VXGI
!/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/GameWorks/VXGI
!/Engine/Binaries/ThirdParty/GameWorks/VXGI/*.dll
# etc..
# NVCHANGE_END: Add VXGI
```

What is this pattern called? Is it a git thing? After going through a difficult git merge that lacked such comments, I'm keen to adopt something similar but I don't yet understand what it is.

Comment: For clarification, are you seeing these markers in your _source_ code?

Comment: This is not a git thing. This is something they made up. In my experience, these tags quickly become clutter. (Imagine a file with twenty such tags, all overlapping.)